# How to open Google Maps app instead of opening it in Webview?

Tags: flutter, url-launcher

I want to open Google Maps app in Android. I have this code for this:

```
Future<void> openMapApp() async {
    String query = Uri.encodeComponent(adress);
    String googleUrl = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$query';
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      try {
        if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(googleUrl))) {
          await launchUrl(Uri.parse(googleUrl));
        }
      } catch (error, stack) {
        await Sentry.captureException(error, stackTrace: stack);
        throw ("Cannot launch Google map");
      }
    }
}
```

but it's opening in Webview.

I want specifically to open it in Google Maps app, it is actually possible?
I have Google Maps installed.

Comment: `maps://search/?api=1&query=$query`

Comment: @Nagual ```component name for maps://search/?api=1&query=Wroc%C5%82aw%2C%20Podwale%2037%2F38 is null```
I need lat, lng to this? Because I have city and street in my query

Comment: I can't test syntax right now but I'm sure the url should starts with `maps:` or `geo:`

Comment: It's ```geo```. Thank you so much, I cannot find anything about that.

Comment: Do you know [map_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/map_launcher) package?